# vhdl package signals modelsim wlf

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, vlsi

I'm using Modelsim command line simulation & producing WLF of all signals. Language is VHDL.

The problem is that, I've many signals defined in VHDL package, but those signals are not available in WLF after simulation is over.

Is there any command or modelsim.ini to be modified to dump package signals to WLF?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use the library from the top level of your simulation you can do:

```
log -r /package_name/*
```

or just

```
log -r /*
```

Just doing the following does not cause package signals to be included.

```
log -r *
```

Comment: I haven't tried "log -r /package_name/*" will try & post the results... thanks kraigher

Comment: i've a **add_wave.do** which i pass to **vsim** during simulation. in that do file   `add wave /tb_top/module_name/*` adds  the signals defined in that module only. but  `add wave /tb_top/package_name/*` gives error during simulation

Comment: Did you try `-r /package_name/*` or `-r /*` as I wrote in my post?

Comment: In    add wave -r  /*    also package defined signals not available in WLF. Error occurred when using package name as said before